# How to get the range of a specific word in Word Document using Word Interop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ms-word, office-interop

I am creating a C# program that inserts a table inside a word document. Now, I need to insert a table in a certain position in different word documents. All word documents/templates I have has the word `<table>` in it where I want to insert the table. For me to be able to insert the table in that particular word document position, I need to get the range of the location of the word `<table>`. Is there any possible way to get the range of that particular word inside the word document?

All I can see in the references I have searched are getting ranges using the count of a space, word, sentence, etc. such as the following:

```
object start = doc.Words[2].Start; //start of the second word
object end = doc.Words[2].End; // start of the third word

Word.Range myRange = doc.Range(ref start, ref end);
```

Since the number of words inside my word document is dynamic, the code above is not very helpful.

Is there any way to get the range of a specific word inside a word document using C# word interop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Find` object of an empty (or indeed any) `Range` to set the bounds of the range to a particular word/string in the document:

```
Word.Range range = document.Range(0, 0);
if (range.Find.Execute("<table>")) {
    // range is now set to bounds of the word "<table>"
}
```

The `Execute` method has additional parameters (for performing a case-insensitive match, etc).